# Error using foreign keys in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I used the foreign key

After I clicked the delete button

runs MessageBox.Show("Error");

Because It is a foreign key

After I clicked the delete button

I do not want to insert the table

Again gives the same error, delete

Never
  I can not insert or update the table

Again gives the same error, delete

How the problem is solved

code delete

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int del = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);

            T1 query = (from p in db.T1 where p.id == del select p).FirstOrDefault();

            db.T1.Remove(query);
            db.SaveChanges();
            fill();
        }
        catch
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }

    }
```

code insert

```
try
        {


            db.T1.Add(new T1()
                {
                    names=textBox1.Text
                });
            db.SaveChanges();
            //fill();
        }
        catch
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

class code first

```
public partial class T1
{
    public T1()
    {
        this.T2 = new List<T2>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string names { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<T2> T2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class T2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> fname { get; set; }
    public virtual T1 T1 { get; set; }
}
```

sql setup
http://sarbandi.ir/keramati/SQLPackage.exe

code example 
http://sarbandi.ir/keramati/examample.rar

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `T1` object you try to delete also has `T2` objects in its collection (as you say *I used the foreign key*). So the first problem, the delete, is probably solved by

```
T1 t1 = db.T1.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == del);
   // Same as your code, just other syntax, or: db.T1.Find(del);

foreach(var t2 in t1.T2.ToList())
{
    db.T2.Remove(t2);
}
db.T1.Remove(t1);

db.SaveChanges();
```

The second error is probably caused by the fact that you have one `DbContext` instance (`db`). The second time you try to save, `db` does a second effort to commit the delete that failed before, but that's still in there. (If you'd catch the exception in stead of swallowing it you could confirm this). Your delete and insert actions should each use their own context instance that you new up in a `using` construct:

```
using(var db = new MyContext())
{
    // do stuff.
}
```

Side notes:

- try to separate UI and data logic if this is meant to be more than just some exercise.
- catch exceptions: `catch(Exception exception)` in stead of just showing a messagebox.

(I must admit I didn't look at your links, I hope this will bring you in the right track).